# Changing ArcSDE connections number without SDE command toolkit?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service

In arcgis 10.2 is there any way to change the config properties and specifically the max connections of the sde without having to install and use the sde commands?

Answer (score 1):

Use your DBMS tools to edit the [SERVER_CONFIG system table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002n0000000z000000), parameter named CONNECTIONS.

> The SERVER_CONFIG (sde_server_config in SQL Server and PostgreSQL)
>   table contains initialization parameters and values that define how an
>   enterprise geodatabase uses memory. The parameters and their default
>   values are listed in the "Initialization parameters" section of this
>   topic.

Comment: My services increase too much because I am publishing cached services. Is it normal that the connections never close ? Should I mind to turn them off? or cached services are keeping them by default open and as a result I MUST increase the connections pool ?

Comment: @Smalis that is another question and you should ask it separately.